# How to detect selection change on a JTree was made by the keyboard or the mouse?

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtree, listeners

Is there a way on a Tree Selection Listener to know if the selection change was made by a keyboard event or a mouse event? I would like to trigger different event for these two.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a mouselistener, and a keylistener, and manually calculate what one they chose, and do your specific stuff there.

Comment: If I understand fully, it would be like storing the nature of the last event and use the result in the selection listener? It may work. But, could I be sure that my mouse listener or key listener would be called before the selection listener? (I'll give it a try, through.)

Comment: I would debug it, check if getting the selected object in your mouselistener returns the current one, or the last one. If it does the current one (the one you just chose), great! You can do all your handler there, no calculations. If not though, you'll need to do some other stuff (such as tree.getClosestPathForLocation(x, y)), and for the keylistener, take the old one, if you hit down, get the one beneath it, up above it

Comment: Your solution implementing a MouseListener and KeyListener to record the last event type seems to gives great results. I just wish the Selection Listener will never be called before that Key/Mouse Listeners, but the documentation gives me no garantie.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it handles all the mouse + key events first, then calls all the listeners that were affected by it (such as the TreeSelectionListeners). Glad it worked though :)

Comment: Key and Mouse events can also happen and not modify the selection. This may leave orphaned state for a later selection change event. Furthermore, @BéatriceCassistat's worry is valid. Selection change happens from a mouse/key event, but this is outside the developer's control and may be fired before or after the developer's mouse/key event listener's execution. Selection change may also happen from other sources. There is so much room for bugs here. I don't think this is a good idea. I have the same need to discern how the selection change was initiated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can know if the selection change originated from a keyboard event or a mouse event. Inside the selection change listener, use this code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.*;
...
AWTEvent event = EventQueue.getCurrentEvent();
if ( event instanceof MouseEvent) {
    System.out.println("selection change: got mouse event");
} else if ( event instanceof KeyEvent) {
    System.out.println("selection change: got key event");
} else {
    System.out.println("selection change: got something else");
}
```

This should work for all types of AWT and Swing events. It should tell you in all cases what event is being currently processed. It will, however, only tell you the highest level event... that is, the event that was dispatched on the `EventQueue`. In the case of the OP, that event - a Mouse or Key event - later triggers a selection change "event", which isn't really an event in terms of AWT or Swing, but you might think of it as one since its class is named `TreeSelectionEvent`. But it all depends on how the event is processed and whether it uses the `EventQueue`.

Note that if a listener method calls code that fires other events - like say, `AbstractTableModel.fireTableDataChanged` or `JPanel.add` - then it's possible the current event will be overwritten by a new current event (and when finished will not be restored to the event you're interested in). So for the approach I outline to work, you'll want to grab the current event early in your processing and store it. I believe this will be much more robust than the other approach given suggesting Key and Mouse event listeners. I'm using this approach successfully now.